# Laravel vue.js and vuex link body text by id and show in a new component

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuex

I am very new to Laravel and Vuex, I have a simple array of post on my page.

test 1

test 2

test 3

I am trying to link the text on the AppPost.vue component and show the post that has been clicked on a new component (AppShowpost.vue) on the same page. I believe I have to get the post by id and change the state? any help would be good. Thank you.

when you click test 1 it will show "test 1" on a new component (AppShowpost.vue)

In side my store timeline.js, I belive I need to get the post by id and change the state ?

```
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
    namespaced: true,

    state: {
        posts: []
    },

    getters: {
        posts (state) {
            return state.posts
        }
    },

    mutations: {
        PUSH_POSTS (state, data) {
            state.posts.push(...data)
        }
    },

    actions: {
        async getPosts ({ commit }) {
            let response = await axios.get('timeline')

            commit('PUSH_POSTS', response.data.data)
        }
    }
}
```

My AppTimeline.vue component

```
<template>
    <div>
        <app-post
            v-for="post in posts"
            :key="post.id"
            :post="post"
        />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import { mapGetters, mapActions } from 'vuex'

    export default {
        computed: {
            ...mapGetters({
                posts: 'timeline/posts'
            })
        },
        
        methods: {
            ...mapActions({
                getPosts: 'timeline/getPosts'
            })
        },

        mounted () {
            this.getPosts()
        }
    }
</script>
```

My AppPost.vue component. I need to link the post.body to display the post in my AppShowpost.vue component.

```
<template>
    <div class="w-full inline-block p-4">
       <div class="flex w-full">
            <p>
              <a href="#" @click.prevent="">  {{ post.body }} </a>
            </p>
       </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            post: {
                required: true,
                type: Object
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

My AppSowpost.vue component that needs to display the post that is clicked.

```
<template>
    <div>
        // Displaypost ?
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        // Get post from id ?
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You need to watch for the state change. If it changes, then get the list of posts.

Comment: yeah I just don't know how to set that up in vuex  :(

Answer (score 1):

Okay you can create a new state in your vuex "current_state", asyou said, you can dispatch a mutation by passing the id to the vuex.

```
 state: {
    posts: [],
    current_state_id : null
},
```

In your mutations

```
 set_state_id (state, data) {
    state.current_state_id = data;
 }
```

On your app post.vue, you can set a computed property that watches the current state

```
computed: {
  currentState() {
    return this.$store.getters["timeline/current_state_id"];
}}
```

And create a watcher for the computed property to display the current id/post

```
watch: {
  currentState: function(val) {
   console.log(val);
},
```

Comment: Ok what so I put in the Appshowpost component ? how do I display the post from the id ? and how do I link the id of the post to post.body link on the AppPost.vue component ? ..Thanks for your help :) 
```` 
<a href="#" @click.prevent="">  {{ post.body }} </a>
````

Comment: @StuartCompaan so you have a list of posts correct? You can find it using the id. Just use  const post = this.posts.find(post => post.id === this.currentState);

Comment: sorry i am very new to vue.js and vuex so I dont know how to grab the id in a different component ...where do I put  const post = posts.find(post => post.id === this.currentState);

Comment: Its okay bro I understand. In your ShowAppPost.vue, you can put it under the watch function for currentState that I posted earlier. The watch function will trigger if the state id has changed. Once you get the id, then you can use your vuex posts getter to find the current post id.

Comment: Thank you so much ...I will play around with it and let you know :)

Comment: I just cant get it to work...how do i link the anchor tag in the AppPost.vue so it will change the post out put on the AppShowpost.vue componenet ? <a href="#" @click.prevent=""> {{ post.body }} </a>

Comment: have not had time to play around with it ...but thank you for your help ..if I get it all working I will let u know :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help you. First I will recommend to use `router-link`. Read about router link [here](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-link) if your interested. It is very helpful and easy to use. But you will have to define the url and pass parameter on our vue-route(see bellow).

**1**.You can wrap your `post.body` in router-link as follow.

```
//With this approach, you don't need any function in methods
<router-link :to="'/posts/show/' + post.id">
     {{ post.body }}
</router-link>
```

**2.** In your AppSowpost.vue component, you can find the post in vuex state based on url params as follow.

```
<template>
  <div> {{ thisPost.body }} </div>
</template>

// ****************

computed: {
  ...mapState({ posts: state=>state.posts }),

// Let's get our single post with the help of url parameter passed on our url
thisPost() { return this.posts.find(p => p.id == this.$route.params.id) || {}; }
},

mounted() { this.$store.dispatch("getPosts");}
```

**3**. Let's define our vue route.

```
path: "posts/show/:id",
name: "showpost",
params: true, // Make sure the params is set to true
component: () => import("@/Components/AppShowPost.vue"),
```

Your Mutations should look as simple as this.

```
mutations: {
    PUSH_POSTS (state, data) {
        state.posts = data;
    }
},
```

Please let me know how it goes.

Comment: thank you ..I will look in to this :) I'm just finding it hard to get my head around vue and vuex with laravel lol

Comment: Once you learn vuex, it will make your live more easier when it comes to managing data. If my answer helped, please vote it and mark it as the correct one. I'm pretty sure it will work.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I am getting this error ? 
ERROR in ./resources/js/app.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@/Components/AppShowPost.vue' in '/home/stuie/www/authlinks/resources/js'
 @ ./resources/js/app.js 20:11-49
 @ multi ./resources/js/app.js ./resources/sass/app.scss

Comment: My app.js has this?
````
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
Vue.use(VueRouter)

const router = new VueRouter({
 mode: 'history',
 path: "posts/show/:id",
 name: "showpost",
 params: true, // Make sure the params is set to true
 component: () => import("@/Components/AppShowPost.vue")
});

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    store,
    router
});
````